# Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') in storybook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, styles, storybook

I am working in Vue3 with Storybook
In a component I am using this function

```
function div_show(id) { 
      const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("innerright");
      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 != id) {
          elements[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      elements[id - 1].style.display = "block";  
    }
```

It is working fine when I am using the function in App.vue.
When I use this component in Storybook it gives me this error.

Can anyone please help me how can I resolve it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4P5x.png)

Comment: perhaps you call the function with an `id` that is beyond the number of `elements`

Comment: Please, provide full example of code.

Comment: The error means that `elements[id - 1]` is undefined.